# How can I get a new instance for each request in StructureMap?

Tags: structuremap

I want a new instance of my object for each ObjectFactory.Getinstance() call with StructureMap. I haven't been able to find it or figure it out myself.

AlwaysUnique isn't doing it.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetConcreteInstanceOf_ShouldReturn_DifferentInstance()
{
  ObjectFactory.Initialize(registry =>
  {
    // setup the singleton, so that it's new every time
    registry.For<ISystemData>().AlwaysUnique().Use(new SystemDataClient());
  });

  ISystemData result = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISystemData>();
  ISystemData result2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISystemData>();
  Assert.AreNotSame(result, result2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a new instance every time, then you don't want a singleton, by definition. Instead of passing an instance, just specify the concrete type, and StructureMap's default behavior will give you a new instance each time:

```
registry.For<ISystemData>().Use<SystemDataClient>();
```

Comment: Isn't `registry.For<ISystemData>().Use<SystemDataClient>();` sufficient in this case? Why bother with the lambda expression?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's what I get for typing without thinking... thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a greedy constructor that interferes with the already accepted answer, you can also use this:

```
registry.For<ISystemData>().Use(() => new SystemDataClient());
```